# bullet physics constraints don't appear to have any effect

Tags: c++, 3d, constraints, physics, bullet

I've tried setting up first a 6dof constraint. However whether I add the constraint or not, the rigid bodies behave the same, dropping straight to the ground and i can drag and throw them around freely. So I added a slider constraint to test if it was just a problem with my 6dof setup. Still no luck. I've looked at the bullet source constraints demos, even some of my old code that successfully uses bullet constraints. Am I missing something simple in my initialization that maybe fresh eyes can spot?

edit: using bullet 2.81 rev 2613

bullet setup

```
btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase =new btDbvtBroadphase();
btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration =new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher =new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* solver =new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;
bullet_dynamics_world =new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(
    dispatcher,broadphase,solver,collisionConfiguration);
bullet_dynamics_world->setGravity(btVector3(0,-10.0f,0));
```

rigid body setup

```
btConvexHullShape* part_shape(new btConvexHullShape());
part_shape->addPoint(vp0);
part_shape->addPoint(vp1);
part_shape->addPoint(vp2);
part_shape->addPoint(vp3);
btVector3 intertia(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
part_shape->calculateLocalInertia(1.0,intertia);

start_trans.setOrigin(start_trans.getOrigin()+center);

quetz::CBulletMotionState* motion_state(new CBulletMotionState(part, start_trans));

btRigidBody* part_body(0);

btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo inf(1.0f, motion_state, part_shape,intertia);
part_body =new btRigidBody(inf);
part_body->setUserPointer(this);
part_body->setMotionState(motion_state);
part_body->setWorldTransform(motion_state->absolute_transform);
part_body->setActivationState(DISABLE_DEACTIVATION);

core->bullet_dynamics_world->addRigidBody(part_body);
```

constraint setup code

```
btTransform fromA(btTransform::getIdentity());
btTransform fromB(btTransform::getIdentity());

fromA.setOrigin( btVector3(-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
fromB.setOrigin( btVector3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f));

btRigidBody* ref_bodyA(partA->m_physics);

btSliderConstraint* bt_constraint =
    new btSliderConstraint(
        *ref_bodyA,
        fromB,true);

bt_constraint->setLowerLinLimit(-10.0f);
bt_constraint->setUpperLinLimit(10.0f);

bt_constraint->setLowerAngLimit(0.0f);
bt_constraint->setUpperAngLimit(0.0f);

core->bullet_dynamics_world->addConstraint(bt_constraint, false);
```

Comment: ok, it was something really embarrassing. one of my own functions was not returning anything, in a non-void return. I don't know why I didn't get any segfaults. probably because I was in debug mode. marking as solved when it lets me (new user)